# Visual Studio debug assertion failed dialog unresponsive

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

When debugging a native win32 application, certain unhandled exceptions (more specifically a failed assertion in Windows `atlcomcli.h`) causes the "unhandled exception" dialog (where you can **abort**, **continue** (to debug the exception in visual studio) or **ignore**) to *freeze* and be *unresponsive* - none of the buttons can be pressed.

This means I cannot get the callstack among other things, I have to force-terminate Visual Studio and so I cant get any help on debugging where it crashes.

It works just fine with most other unhandled exceptions that are thrown.

Why is this?

Comment: It would be helpful to have some code that could reproduce the issue.

Comment: Have you witnessed this on multiple computers? Particular OS? Visual Studio version?

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint in the Windows code right before it opens the dialog box?

Comment: Have you tried navigating the assertion dialog using the keyboard? Particularly inside drag-and-drop implementations it's not uncommon for debug assertion dialogs to not receive any mouse input.

Comment: Windows 10, VS2015. The actual assertion happens outside my code, in the microsoft headers. I did try with keyboard, still unresponsive. I am mainly looking to see if anyone else encountered similiar issues.

Comment: Again, others would probably be very willing to try this exact thing, if you could write a very small program that made the proper calls. [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: The assertion message also appears in the Output window during debugging. You could view the output window, maybe it contains much more helpful error messages.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is that you could collect the minidump file for the crashed/freeze issue, debug the crashed dump file and find more helpful information for it:

[How can I disable the debug assertion dialog on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943665/disable-debug-assertion-dialog-on-windows)