# Disable Assertion error dialog box from windows form

Tags: c#, assert, visual-studio-debugging, assertions, jabberd2

I have a windows form application along with some external libraries such as NEwtonsoft-Json.dll , Zlib.dll and some more libraries for different purpose. sometimes im getting this assertion messagebox with 3 buttons (Ignore,Abort,Retry). The program will continue executing when i press ignore button. after many tutorial i found a solution that , keeping the assertuienabled property as false inside the system.diagnostics Tag will not show these messageboxes. but in my code the error is still exist and which is coming from one of these external library. Any solution guys?
The code inside the app.config are

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <configuration>

        <configSections>
        </configSections>
          <system.diagnostics>
          <assert assertuienabled="false"/>
        </system.diagnostics>
        <startup>
         <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
        </startup>
    </configuration>
```

[image: Screenshot of Error Message]

Comment: The solution depends entirely on the failing assertion. Since there is no information about it in your post, nobody can help you.

Comment: I set assertuienbaled property value as false and still those error messagebox appearing. This is what im asking for

Comment: I'd definitely **fix the issue** that caused assertions to fail instead of trying to silent them.

Comment: Should i share the source code?

Comment: @Lazy Programer, Whether your app was crashed?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39155942/visual-studio-debug-assertion-failed-dialog-unresonsive, I met this issue which was crashed, so collect the dump file would be a workaround, but if your app was not crashed, it would be better if you could share the code.

Comment: No, App is not crashed. This bug always coming from some external library. and how can i find the issue which is happening inside the library?

Comment: @Lazy Programer, No sample is hard for me to troubleshooting this issue, if possible, you could share a simple sample without personal information using one drive, so I could really download and test it in my side. If you want to ignore it, you could try to debug  your app in release mode.

Comment: How can i debug in release mode?

Comment: @Lazy Programer, Just two configurations: Debug and Release, I mean that you could select the Release from the drop down list, and then debug your app using the Release option, view the result. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx0123s5.aspx