# Microsoft Visual Studio C++ Runtime - Disable Debug Assertion from Console

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++-runtime

For the MS Visual Studio C++ Runtime is there a way to disable the Windows Assertion Dialog via an environment variable or in some other non-invasive external way?  That is, do this without recompiling.  [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943665/how-can-i-disable-the-debug-assertion-dialog-on-windows) or [this one](https://github.com/dotnet/llilc/issues/584) point one in the right direction to using `_CrtSetReportMode`, but it requires rebuilding the program, and I can't do that.

Is there an environment variable or something that I can set to so that child processes just exit with the appropriate error code?  I don't want to disable this for all programs, just this one (hence why an environment variable would be appropriate), but if a global setting or something is all I can get then so be it.

Maybe there's a better higher level approach that avoids the problem? I have a testing program that is executing a program on multiple inputs.  The child program can assert at times, and I just want to record the result and continue.

Comment: You *must* rebuild the program, you cannot ship anything built with the Debug configuration.  And it is quite pointless to test it, non-optimized code doesn't suffer from the same kind of flaws.  Contact whomever provided you with the executable code and ask for the correct build.

Comment: You're philosophically right. This project misuses the intent of asserts. They use them where a non-zero exit with diagnostic is more appropriate. It is extremely frustrating. Worst case, I can temporarily modify the source, but I was hoping for some external configuration.