# Visual Studio 2017 - Assert Failure is not putting up prompt?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging

All of a sudden VS2017 doesn't display the Abort, Ignore, Retry prompt when it is hitting an `assert()` failure.   All it does is output to the `output` window and exit the program so I can't debug it.

I did a repair install, didn't change anything. JIT is enabled (native code), using debugging version and libraries.   It's been working fine.

That is the error I am getting:

```
Press Retry to debug the application - JIT must be enabled)Assertion failed!
Program: C:\Test\x64\Debug\Test.exe  
File: C:\Test\Test\owner-draw-buttons.cpp  
Line: 144  
Expression: 0 

    For information on how your program can cause an assertion failure, see the 
Visual C++ documentation on asserts (Press Retry to debug the application - JIT 
must be enabled)Debug Error! Program: C:\Test\x64\Debug\Test.exe abort() has 
been called (Press Retry to debug the application) The thread 0x3524 has exited 
with code 3 (0x3). The program '[10772] Test.exe' has exited with code 3 (0x3).
```

Any ideas on how to fix?

TIA!!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please upload the errors you are getting and bring more details: what were you doing? which exact error you get? Which one is your setup?

Comment: (Press Retry to debug the application - JIT must be enabled)Assertion failed!

Program: C:\Test\x64\Debug\Test.exe
File: C:\Test\Test\owner-draw-buttons.cpp
Line: 144

Expression: 0

For information on how your program can cause an assertion
failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts

(Press Retry to debug the application - JIT must be enabled)Debug Error!

Program: C:\Test\x64\Debug\Test.exe
abort() has been called
(Press Retry to debug the application)
The thread 0x3524 has exited with code 3 (0x3).
The program '[10772] Test.exe' has exited with code 3 (0x3).

Comment: I'm having this issue, but only when an assertion fires while handling certain WM events in my WndProc (while not it others)

Answer (score 0):

For `JIT is enabled (native code)`, maybe you're in a C++ project. I can only guess it have something to do with `Windows SDK` version and the `ucrtbase.dll` in it.

**To resolve that:**

1.Please try updating your VS2017 to latest 15.9.17

2.Updating your windows OS to a newer version(1903 in my machine), see this [similar issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/52544/view.html)(the download link is invalid, I suggest you update Windows system directly instead of installing the sdk separately).

After that, restart PC and create a simple C++ console project with `assert(false);` to check if now the dialog comes back. Hope it helps :)

In addition, as a temporary workaround, you can try `_CrtSetReportMode` and `_CrtSetReportFile`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31611163/10910450).

Comment: What's weird is if on the main module I use assert(0), it works, but within the other modules (which is during a SubClass callback handler) it doesn't.  See comment above for sample output.

Comment: Hi friend ,could you please create a [minimal code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help us reproduce this issue, it would make great help when we research it.