# Can't suppress MSVC assertion failure dialog

Tags: visual-c++

I've tried this SO answer: [How can I disable the debug assertion dialog on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13943665/how-can-i-disable-the-debug-assertion-dialog-on-windows).

Still, no luck.

The code I'm using:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>
#include <cassert>

int test(int reportType, char* message, int* returnValue)
{
    return 0;
}

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    _CrtSetReportHook(&test);

    _CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE | _CRTDBG_MODE_DEBUG);
    _CrtSetReportFile(_CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_FILE_STDERR);
    _CrtSetReportMode(_CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE | _CRTDBG_MODE_DEBUG);
    _CrtSetReportFile(_CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_FILE_STDERR);

    //_ASSERT(0);  // works as expected: no dialog appears
    assert(0); // The dialog appears

    return 0;
}
```

Maybe, there is something wrong with my system's config?

Comment: [assert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/assert-macro-assert-wassert?view=msvc-170) docs mention [_set_error_mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/set-error-mode?view=msvc-170#example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[assert documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/assert-macro-assert-wassert?view=msvc-170) notes [_set_error_mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/set-error-mode?view=msvc-170) should be used:

> To override the default output behavior regardless of the app type, call _set_error_mode to select between the output-to-stderr and display-dialog-box behavior.

From their example:

```
_set_error_mode(_OUT_TO_STDERR);
assert(2+2==5);
```